# Has anyone discovered a convex space-filling 15-faced polyhedron?

Tags: geometry, polyhedra, tessellations

I've been looking for extensive surveys regarding space-filling polyhedra, but have only come across Michael Goldbergs "Convex polyhedral space-fillers of more than twelve faces" from 1979, stating that "no one has found a 15 faced space-filler, nor has anyone proved its nonexistence".

I realize that several might have been found since then, but i have no way of verifying it, or checking which types has then been found.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Olaf Delgado-Friedrichs and Michael O’Keeffe, "Isohedral simple tilings: binodal and by tiles with <16 faces" --

"For simple polyhedra with 14, 15 and 16 faces, there are respectively 10, 65 and
434 that fill space and a total of 23, 136 and 710 distinct tilings."

Not all of these are convex, though.

After reading through a lot of papers by Goldberg, I wrote the following for MathWorld's [Space-filling polyhedron](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Space-FillingPolyhedron.html)

In the period 1974-1980, Michael Goldberg attempted to exhaustively catalog space-filling polyhedra. According to Goldberg, there are 27 distinct space-filling hexahedra, covering all of the 7 hexahedra except the pentagonal pyramid. Of the 34 heptahedra, 16 are space-fillers, which can fill space in at least 56 distinct ways. Octahedra can fill space in at least 49 different ways. In pre-1980 papers, there are forty 11-hedra, sixteen dodecahedra, four 13-hedra, eight 14-hedra, no 15-hedra, one 16-hedron originally discovered by Föppl (Grünbaum and Shephard 1980; Wells 1991, p. 234), two 17-hedra, one 18-hedron, six icosahedra, two 21-hedra, five 22-hedra, two 23-hedra, one 24-hedron, and a believed maximal 26-hedron. In 1980, P. Engel (Wells 1991, pp. 234-235) then found a total of 172 more space-fillers of 17 to 38 faces, and more space-fillers have been found subsequently. P. Schmitt discovered a nonconvex aperiodic polyhedral space-filler around 1990, and a convex polyhedron known as the Schmitt-Conway biprism which fills space only aperiodically was found by J. H. Conway in 1993 (Eppstein). A modern survey would be welcome.

So far, I know of no modern survey.  I'll believe all these tilers when I can see them in an interactive 3D program. Goldberg's results need to be cataloged, and Engel's results added in, and then things like this [13-facer](http://science.unitn.it/~gabbrielli/p8_gallery.html) can be considered.

Answer (score 3):

[Yes](http://science.unitn.it/~gabbrielli/sf15h2.txt).

Vertex coordinates:
0 0.293715 0.406952;
0 0.57735 0.225;
0 0.57735 0.462844;
0.141706 -0.0818139 0.490403;
0.173205 0.67735 0.675;
0.326795 -0.188675 0.675;
0.358294 0.370489 -0.0404031;
0.358294 0.570489 0.859597;
0.358294 0.784212 0.490403;
0.5 -0.0050396 0.0430477;
0.5 -0.0886751 0.887156;
0.5 -0.288675 0.225;
0.5 -0.288675 0.462844;
0.5 0.19496 0.943048;
0.641706 0.370489 -0.0404031;
0.641706 0.570489 0.859597;
0.641706 0.784212 0.490403;
0.673205 -0.188675 0.675;
0.826795 0.67735 0.675;
0.858294 -0.0818139 0.490403;
1 0.293715 0.406952;
1 0.57735 0.225;
1 0.57735 0.462844.

This is the only one I am aware of. I made it in [voro++](http://math.lbl.gov/voro++/) by taking the Voronoi partition of a set of 2 points within an 'almost' hexagonal periodic box.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but link-only answers are fragile. If the page is ever moved or deleted, the answer will contain almost no information. Please expand the answer a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Added vertex coordinates to the answer.Please also note that no space-filling simple polyhedron with 15-faces exist.

Comment: I'll be more precise. The work cited by Ed Pegg contains non-convex space-filling 15-faced polyhedra only. Delgado-Friedrichs and O'Keeffe enumerated all the possible isohedral simple tilings there. Unfortunately the requirement for a tiling of being "simple" clashes with those of being made up of convex and 15-faced tiles.